# Errors when running Javascript code in Tomcat

Tags: javascript, tomcat

I want get the number of elements of th tag. This is my source code:

```
<table class="tablehienthi" id="table">
<thead class="theadhienthi">
    <tr>
    <th class="thhienthi">Niên Khóa</th>
    <th class="thhienthi">Hệ Đào Tạo</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tbodyhienthi">
    <tr class="trhienthi">  
    <td class="tdhienthi"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(30, 144, 255);" href="#">Niên Khóa 2010-2015</a></td><td class="tdhienthi">Cư Nhân</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trhienthi">  
    <td class="tdhienthi"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(30, 144, 255);" href="#">Niên Khóa 2010-2015</a></td><td class="tdhienthi">Kỹ Sư</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trhienthi">  
    <td class="tdhienthi"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(30, 144, 255);" href="#">Niên Khóa 2009-2014</a></td><td class="tdhienthi">Cư Nhân</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

When I run code in browser if I don't run it with tomcat then code:

```
$(".tablehienthi tr").children().length return 8
```

otherwise if I run with tomcat:

```
$(".tablehienthi tr").children().length return 0.
```

I don't understand? I want get `$(".tablehienthi tr").children().length` when I run with tomcat. Full my source code:

```
  <body>
    <table class="tablehienthi" id="table">
<thead class="theadhienthi">
    <tr>
    <th class="thhienthi">Niên Khóa</th>
    <th class="thhienthi">Hệ Đào Tạo</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tbodyhienthi">
    <tr class="trhienthi">  
    <td class="tdhienthi"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(30, 144, 255);" href="#">Niên Khóa 2010-2015</a></td><td class="tdhienthi">Cư Nhân</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trhienthi">  
    <td class="tdhienthi"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(30, 144, 255);" href="#">Niên Khóa 2010-2015</a></td><td class="tdhienthi">Kỹ Sư</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trhienthi">  
    <td class="tdhienthi"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(30, 144, 255);" href="#">Niên Khóa 2009-2014</a></td><td class="tdhienthi">Cư Nhân</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script langauage="javascript">
        $('document').ready(function(){
            var temp= $(".tablehienthi th").children().length;
            alert(temp);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: What? How are you expecting to run a jQuery DOM operation in Tomcat? At a minimum, we need a lot more code and context.

Comment: do you want to count table rows  or data ?

Comment: Tomcat runs back end applications. It has nothing to do with the Javascript that is being executed. That is calculated by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

To count table row try this :

```
 <body>
    <table class="tablehienthi" id="table">
<thead class="theadhienthi">
    <tr>
    <th class="thhienthi">Niên Khóa</th>
    <th class="thhienthi">Hệ Đào Tạo</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tbodyhienthi">
    <tr class="trhienthi">  
    <td class="tdhienthi"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(30, 144, 255);" href="#">Niên Khóa 2010-2015</a></td><td class="tdhienthi">Cư Nhân</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trhienthi">  
    <td class="tdhienthi"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(30, 144, 255);" href="#">Niên Khóa 2010-2015</a></td><td class="tdhienthi">Kỹ Sư</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trhienthi">  
    <td class="tdhienthi"><a style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(30, 144, 255);" href="#">Niên Khóa 2009-2014</a></td><td class="tdhienthi">Cư Nhân</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script langauage="javascript">
        $('document').ready(function(){
            var temp= $("tbody tr").length;
            alert(temp);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

To count Table data change the javascript to this :

```
<script langauage="javascript">
            $('document').ready(function(){
                var temp= $("tbody tr").children().length;
                alert(temp);
            });
        </script>
```